# Building assembly and adding embedded resource at run-time - Scenario included

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, embedded-resource

EDIT: To better clarify the issue, I've included a scenario:

**Scenario**: There is an education institution that produces video tutorials. We were asked to provide a solution on how to protect the video files so as not to give access to the real video files to the users. The videos are published "offline" using DVD ROM.

**Solution**: We decided to embed the video files into the silverlight assembly and write a Silverlight OOB application that takes advantage of `MediaElement` control to play video content. This control accepts video resource of type `Stream` which makes it possible to use `Application.GetResourceStream` method to read the embedded resource as an stream and pass it to MediaElement.

**Design:** We need to write two applications:

1. One that accepts one or more video files from education institute operator and creates an assembly and embeds the video files into the assembly.
2. Another application that reads the contents of the newly-created assemblies and plays the video content using MediaElement control.

**Problem:**

How to generate a **silverlight assembly** and embed video resources to it **"programmatically"** using a C# windows app or Silverlight app? I wanted to use `AssemblyBuilder` class, but it does not contain `Save` method in silverlight.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create an Assembly from what? C#? IL? Another assembly? While some of these are technically possible (e.g. by including a compiler in your app), what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I've included the scenario to better clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you feel you need to embed your video in the way you described, rather than stream it, then you do not need to run the creation of modules on the Silverlight client.

- Have the Silverlight app upload the Video to the matching Silverlight host
- Now you have full access to the .Net stack and can create pretty much anything you need (including compiling projects or assemblies on the fly and using `AssemblyBuilder`).

*If this does not cover your situation, please clarify the question further.*